# AWS ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have set up a trigger/lambda to upload into DynamoDB however i get the following error when uploading..not sure what is going wrong.

So far i have just created a blank dDB table with the primary key of "PlayerWeekID" as string but nothing else. Is this an issue because DDB isnt reading in the data types? Do I need to specify these in the Lamdda or set up in DDB before running the code?

Update:
This is the python code:

```
#change dataframe to json
sdl_fpl_data = dffinal.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object('bucket-name','sdl_fpl_data.json') 
obj.put(Body=json.dumps(sdl_fpl_data))
```

Lambda:

```
import boto3
import json
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table = dynamodb.Table('my-table')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)
```

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Item, value:
{
    "GW": "GW1",
    "OR": "2,149,169",
    "GWP": 66,
    "PB": 3,
    "TM": 0,
    "TC": 0,
    "£": 100,
    "Manager": "XXXXX",
    "Team Name": "XXXXXX",
    "Player_Number": "372",
    "TP": 66,
    "PlayerWeekID": "372GW1"
}

, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in lambda_handler
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)
```

Output of jsonDict
[image]

Comment: make sure jsonDict is not an array of json object

Comment: I have updated with my python code. I did make a dataframe into a jsonobject in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the output of your variable `jsonDict`.

DynamoDB needs a JSON object as payload: `{}`

From what I understand it looks like you're trying to save a list `[]`.

Ensure you are saving an object which contains the keys of your table and you should have no issue.

Working example:

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('test')
    

item = {
    "GW": "GW1",
    "OR": "2,149,169",
    "GWP": 66,
    "PB": 3,
    "TM": 0,
    "TC": 0,
    "£": 100,
    "Manager": "XXXXX",
    "Team Name": "XXXXXX",
    "Player_Number": "372",
    "TP": 66,
    "PlayerWeekID": "372GW1"
}
try:    
    res = table.put_item(Item=item)
    print(res)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Hi Lee, have added an example of when I print(jsonDict) in Cloudwatch. It does this for each line of the data

Comment: Are you trying to save a list of objects? That is showing a single item which is fine but from your comment I'm assuming you're trying to save multiple items?

Comment: My python script takes a dataframe, passes it to JSON first. Then, uses boto3 to upload that JSON object into S3 . Then this lambda is to pass this to a DDB table. I think the issue may come from how I've split it in python i.e orient='records' but other methods dont work either

Comment: found further error:

, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in lambda_handler
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example similar to yours which has no issue writing the item

Comment: I've figured out that its because I was convertion the jsonDict incorrectly to a string. But fixed all that, now a new error: [ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key PlayerWeekID expected: S actual: M

Comment: I can quite clearly see that `PlayerWeekID` is a string in the provided output you shared. Can you provide me with the output just before you save the item.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean before I save the item? If you mean jsonDict['PlayerWeekID'] then: {'0': '5853748GW1', '1': '5853748GW2', '2': '5853748GW3', '3': '5853748GW4', '4': '5853748GW5', '5': '5853748GW6', '6': '5853748GW7', '7': '5853748GW8', '8': '5853748GW9', '9': '5853748GW10', '10': '5853748GW11', '11': '5853748GW12', '12': '5853748GW13', '13': '5853748GW14', '14': '5853748GW15', '15': '5853748GW16'}

Comment: Edit: ahh is it because its taking 0,1,2 etc? Think this needs fixing in python as it happens when I conver to dict! Will try that now

Comment: Yea and you are using that as a key so it has to be a single string value or your item will not save.

Comment: I did manage to convert to dict in python with an index, but still get Type Mismatch. or,I get missing the key in item. Very frustrating

Comment: Your partiton key cannot be a map or list. What have you defined as your partition key?

Comment: PlayerWeekID. I've made python DF a dict, then in the lambda, json object to string then dict. Followed most of the rules that I have found, so now perplexed.

Comment: In the latest output you shared with me `PlayerWeekId` was a map. How does it look now?

Comment: When I set index, it lists the PlayerWeekID as such, but doesnt take the string. When i just use to.dict() in python, lambda reads it as {'PlayerWeekID': {'0': '5853748GW1', '1': '5853748GW2', like above. Not sure how to work around this to be honest. i dont have anything else to use as index.

Comment: But you have multiple `PlayerWeekID` there, using PutItem you can only save a single value at a time. So you must parse your object as a list and `Put` each item individually.

Comment: Yes this was it. I tried this about a day ago but i think it was a typo ! Thank you so much